# Filter table by column in R

Tags: r

I would like to filter table if I have column name written in variable. I tried bellow code but it did not work. dat is a data frame, name of column is Name, and I would like to filter by "John".

```
colname <- "Name"
dat[dat$colname %in% "John",]
```

I saw that it works fine if I do not use variable for column name. (Bellow code works fine)

```
dat[dat$"Name" %in% "John",]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the bracket function `[`.

```
colname <- "Name"

dat[dat[[colname]] %in% "John", ]
dat[dat[, colname] %in% "John", ]  # or
#   Name         X1         X2
# 8 John  0.8646536  1.2688507
# 9 John -1.7201559 -0.3125515
```

*Data*

```
dat <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("John", "Linda", "Mary", "Olaf"), class = "factor"), 
    X1 = c(0.758396178001042, -1.3061852590117, -0.802519568703793, 
    -1.79224083446114, -0.0420324540227439, 2.15004261784474, 
    -1.77023083820321, 0.864653594565389, -1.72015589816109, 
    0.134125668141181), X2 = c(-0.0758265646523722, 0.85830054437592, 
    0.34490034810227, -0.582452690107777, 0.786170375925402, 
    -0.692099286413293, -1.18304353631275, 1.26885070606311, 
    -0.31255154601115, 0.0305712590978896)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach with `dplyr` using non-standard evaluation. Using @jay.sf's data

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% filter(!!sym(colname) == "John")

#  Name        X1        X2
#1 John  0.864654  1.268851
#2 John -1.720156 -0.312552
```

In `data.table`, we can use `get`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[get(colname) == "John"]
```

Since we have only one value to compare we can use `==` here instead of `%in%`.

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`, we can use `eval`  with `as.symbol`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[eval(as.symbol(colname)) == "John"]
#  Name         X1         X2
#1: John  0.8646536  1.2688507
#2: John -1.7201559 -0.3125515
```